# Twitter's Fabric SDK import in gradle freezes AndroidStudio

Tags: android, twitter, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Don't know if it is a AndroidStudio Bug, Fabric problem or configuration problem.
Because AndroidStudio freezes I cannot access to the debug log to get the error message. Executing `./gradlew build` from the command line also fails.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownTaskException: Task with path 'testDebugClasses' not found in project ':app'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.getByPath(DefaultTaskContainer.java:150)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.resolveTask(DefaultTaskContainer.java:144)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskDependency.resolve(DefaultTaskDependency.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:86)
at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmpyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:112)
at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:64)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.doResolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:74)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.resolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:63)
... 65 more
```

This is my setup:

Android Studio 1.0.1

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:2.4.+'
        classpath 'com.github.jcandksolutions.gradle:android-unit-test:2.0.+'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.+'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'retrolambda'
android {

}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
repositories {
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey" android:value="XXXXX"/>
```

crashlytics.properties

```
apiSecret=XXXXXXXX
twitterPluginId=YYYYY
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem.
It was not related with Fabric at all but a missed dependency injection with Dagger. Because I could't see the error log in AndroidStudio I thought it was a Fabric problem.